# doing NSURLRequest and pass value through form-variable

Tags: cocoa, nsmutableurlrequest

i would like to do a HTTP POST method to communicate with an ASPX page.
I will need to pass the value through form-variable.

how can i achieve it on objective-c?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.cimgf.com/2010/02/12/accessing-the-cloud-from-cocoa-touch/

This was the first entry on Google. Please search Google prior to asking questions here :)

Comment: thanx david. the information is indeed very useful... i have tried searching in google first.. i always do.. but i did not come across the link that you have posted here.. this is the answer that i need. thanks again.. cheers

Comment: Yit Ming, you are saying that this answer solved your issue, hence you should accept it by checking the gray checkmark to the left of this answer.